# forEach wait after every 100 cycle

Tags: javascript, node.js

Doing like this:

```
let withEachImageDo = (files) => {
    files.forEach(function(imagePath, index) {
        setTimeout(() => {
         generateImageThumnail(imagePath);
       }, index * 1000);
    })
}
```

will slow down the loop after every file for 1 second. How would I wait 1 sec after every multiple of 100?

Comment: No, it will not "slow the loop down". It will set a series of timeouts with increasing wait times. The loop itself will be finished long before the first `generateImteThumbnail` is called ...

Comment: That's not what this does. It will run through loop setting timeouts for all files for approximately 1 second later. The loop will be completed way before the first timeout is triggered. It will then run each `generateImageThumbnail` as fast as possible.

Comment: Technically the loop will complete immediately but the code `setTimeout` will send to the event queue  to execute later after time full filled. You can wrap the setTimeout inside a `Promise` ( and use `await` )and use `for` loop instead of `forEach`.

Comment: yes of course to all! thanks for pointing out!

Comment: Just use `setTimeout(…, Math.floor(index / 100) * 1000)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have a better time turning `withEachImageDo` into an `async` function, and grabbing a trusty old async delay function from our toolbag.

```
async function delay(ms) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

let withEachImageDo = async (files) => {
  for (let index = 0; index < files.length; index++) {
    const imagePath = files[index];
    generateImageThumnail(imagePath);  // This should probably be async too?
    if (index && index % 100 == 0) {
      await delay(1000);
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: hey @AKX thanks a lot. this does it! I think there is only a little typo: should be `for (let index = 0; index < files.length; index++)` ? index instead of i?